# GridSearchCV with custom Kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def tanimotoKernel(xs, ys):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        a += min(x, y)
        b += max(x, y)
    return a / b

def tanimotoLambdaKernel(xs,ys, gamma = 0.01):
    return np.exp(gamma * tanimotoKernel(xs,ys)) / (np.exp(gamma) - 1)

def GramMatrix(X1, X2, K_function=tanimotoLambdaKernel):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X1.shape[0], X2.shape[0]))
    for i, x1 in enumerate(X1):
        for j, x2 in enumerate(X2):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K_function(x1, x2)
    return gram_matrix

X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
accuracy_score(clf.predict(x_test), y_test)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel=GramMatrix)
```

However, I would like to be able to tune the `gamma` parameter of `tanimotoLambdaKernel` with `GridSearchCV`, because I don't want to have to manually test the parameter, check for the accuracy, etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible directly; the builtin kernels' parameters are all baked in.

One approach is to pass different kernels themselves.  This is a little involved because of your nested functions defining the kernel, so I use `partial`:

```py
from functools import partial
param_space = {
    kernel: [
        partial(
            GramMatrix,
            K_function=partial(
                tanimotoLambdaKernel,
                gamma=g,
            )
        )
        for g in <your list of gammas>
    ]
}
```

The other approach that comes to mind is a custom class.  This is cleaner in the hyperparameter search because "the hyperparameter" can be just `gamma`, but potentially more work in maintaining the class.  In this case I avoid overriding `__init__` by reusing the `gamma` parameter, and I set the kernel at `fit` time so that `set_params` works properly for `gamma`.

```py
class SVC_tanimoto(svm.SVC):
    """SVC with a Tanimoto kernel."""
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        self.kernel = partial(
            GramMatrix,
            K_function=partial(
                tanimotoLambdaKernel,
                gamma=self.gamma,
            )
        )
        super().fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
        return self
```

Comment: I think there is a way to do it using a wrapper class, I saw it some time ago, but I have been searching for it and can't find it.

Comment: @Norhther, I've added a custom class implementation, but I haven't yet tested that it clones and sets params correctly for a hyperparameter search.

Comment: Some errors with the unexpected `nu` parameter, and also after that, `Cannot clone object SVC_tanimoto(gamma=0), as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter gamma`

Comment: Ugh, of course `nu` shouldn't be there.  I copied from `SVC`, which inherits from `BaseSVC` and sets `nu=0`.  You could probably inherit from just `BaseSVC`, but maybe it's best to stick to `SVC` and remove `nu`.  I'll have to look into the `gamma` issue, but possibly/probably it's because `SVC` has its own `gamma`.

Comment: Alright, the double-use of `gamma` was the source of the error, but setting the kernel only at `__init__` was more troublesome than that: setting the gamma parameter wouldn't change the value in the kernel.  So I've moved that into a "prefit" step, and hijacked the original `gamma` to carry this kernel's `gamma` (which is maybe correct anyway from a pedagogical standpoint, I'm not sure).

Comment: I see, so `GridSearchCV` constructs each `SVC` with the appropiate `gamma` parameter and at the `fit` step you overwrite the `kernel`. Thanks! Also, do you think there is a way to do this without the `hijacking` step? Given the case that maybe I want to tune another parameter.